# passing an anonymous function to another function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function

I understand you can pass a function as an argument to another function like so

```
var fn = function(){alert('Hello')}
    function outer(a,fn){
    fn();
    }
```

How can you pass an anonymous function to another function and have it invoked within the function after taking a parameter from the outer function?

```
function outer(function(x){alert(x);})
{
var xVar = "foo";
//..would liked to pass xVar to the anaonymous function 
//passed as a param to the function so that "foo" is displayed as message... 
}
```

Please note changing the signature of outer would be the last choice.

Comment: None of your examples are really valid...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're confusing function invocation (calling a function) with function declaration (defining a function). Here's how do what you ask:

```
// declare the outer function
function outer(func)
{
    var xVar = 'foo';
    func(xVar)
}

// now invoke it
outer(function (x)
{
    alert(x);
});
```

Comment: That's true, but the OP specifically asked about using an anonymous function, which `alert` is not.